# Arduino and Windows serial communications issue?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, arduino

I am working on a project that involves some 'c' serial communication implemented in Visual Studio 2010 Proffesional on a Windows 7 32-bit platform connected to an Arduino Mega device (to control some hardware **not relevant to problem). The code for this works 100%; the ONLY problem I'm having is that something very funny is going on with my serial communication.

The Visual C program is as follows.

```
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(L"COM5",
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            0,
                            0); //Open COM handle (create file)
if (hDevice !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) //If COM3 connected
{
    printf("Com port opened\n");
    DCB lpTest;
    GetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);
    lpTest.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    lpTest.ByteSize = 8;
    lpTest.Parity = NOPARITY;
    lpTest.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    SetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);
    DWORD btsIO;
    WriteFile(hDevice,c1,strlen(c1),&btsIO,NULL);
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
}
```

The output of this program is a text string, and I'm 100% happy with it (should end in Null, have x characters, etc.).

Typing the result obtained from this program in Serial Communicator, it does not seem to work! Using a COM spy program, I am able to obtain the "handshaking" protocols from the terminal application.

However, it seems that communication with the Arduino board works on HyperTerminal and not on Serial Communicator or any other serial applications (no handshaking, etc. is done on the Arduino board **not relevant).

The following "handshaking" was obtained from HyperTerminal (THIS WORKS!!)

```
*
COM port is opened
In/out queue size 8192/8192
Baud rate 9600
DTR on
Data bits=8, Stop bits=1, Parity=None
Set chars: Eof=0x00, Error=0x00, Break=0x00, Event=0x00, Xon=0x11, Xoff=0x13
Handflow: ControlHandShake=(DTR_CONTROL, CTS_HANDSHAKE, ERROR_ABORT), FlowReplace=    (TRANSMIT_TOGGLE, RTS_HANDSHAKE, XOFF_CONTINUE), XonLimit=80, XoffLimit=200
Set timeouts: ReadInterval=10, ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0, ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=0,     WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0,     WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=5000
*
```

And this is from Serial Communicator (it does not work; incorrect and inconsistent numbers):

```
*
COM port is opened
In/out queue size 2048/2048
Baud rate 9600
RTS off
DTR off
Data bits=8, Stop bits=1, Parity=None
Set chars: Eof=0x00, Error=0x00, Break=0x00, Event=0x00, Xon=0x11, Xoff=0x13
Handflow: ControlHandShake=(), FlowReplace=(), XonLimit=80, XoffLimit=200
Set timeouts: ReadInterval=0, ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0, ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=0,     WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0, WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=0
*
```

I can obviously see the differences but need to know how to make the Arduino board independent of these "handshaking" protocols. (DTR, timing, etc.)

And this is from my Visual Studio program (does not work; incorrect and inconsistent numbers)

```
*
COM port is opened
Baud rate 9600
RTS off
DTR off
Data bits=8, Stop bits=1, Parity=None
Set chars: Eof=0x00, Error=0x00, Break=0x00, Event=0x00, Xon=0x11, Xoff=0x13
Handflow: ControlHandShake=(), FlowReplace=(), XonLimit=80, XoffLimit=200
*
```

Thus I would like to get the Arduino board away from DTR and all handshaking, as I want the final implementation to "speak" directly from Visual Studio to the Arduino board.

********UPDATE****************

Thanks for the advice, the thing is I do not understand is why an open source piece of hardware would require so much handshaking.. That is, why does only the worst serial terminal program work where Serial Communicator, advance serial monitor, terterm, terminal, etc. don't seem to work?

I have updated my code to mirror HyperTerminal exactly (complete all handshaking), but it does not seem to work!

Heres the updated code fragement:

```
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(L"COM5",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ |     FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0); //Open COM handle (create file)
if (hDevice !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) //If COM3 connected
{
    printf("Com port opened\n"); //Show it's open
    DCB lpTest;
    // Initialize the DCBlength member.
    lpTest.DCBlength = sizeof (DCB);
    GetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest); //com state
    lpTest.BaudRate = CBR_9600;//load baud
    lpTest.ByteSize = 8;// load no. bits
    lpTest.Parity = NOPARITY;//parity
    lpTest.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;//stop bits

    lpTest.fBinary = FALSE;            // Binary mode; no EOF check
    lpTest.fOutxCtsFlow = TRUE;         // No CTS output flow control
    lpTest.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;         // No DSR output flow control
    lpTest.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;  // DTR flow control type
    lpTest.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;      // DSR sensitivity
    lpTest.fTXContinueOnXoff = TRUE;     // XOFF continues Tx
    lpTest.fOutX = FALSE;                // No XON/XOFF out flow control
    lpTest.fInX = FALSE;                 // No XON/XOFF in flow control
    lpTest.fErrorChar = FALSE;           // Disable error replacement
    lpTest.fNull = FALSE;                // Disable null stripping
    //lpTest.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE; //// RTS flow control
    lpTest.fAbortOnError = TRUE;        // Do not abort reads/writes on error
    SetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);
    DWORD btsIO;
    //ETC
}
```

The result **is exactly the same as the working result from HyperTerminal** except there is no timing conditions. However, I have used a 1 second delay after this code before closing the port.

Is the issue with my write statement?

```
WriteFile(hDevice,c1,strlen(c1),&btsIO,NULL); //Write string to serial
```

It seems like there is something fundamentally wrong that I am doing, and I can't find it!

********************UPDATE2************************

I have stumbled across something, how would I configure my program to send each character individually?

Visual Studio does not allow me to remove the Null or send one character in the code:

```
 WriteFile(hDevice,c1,strlen(c1),&btsIO,NULL);//WRITE STRING TO SERIAL
```

How do I fix this problem? It seems like the Arduino board only accepts one character at a time.

I have edited the character variables to be one char, etc.!

**************UPDATE3***************************************

This are the results from monitoring the communication from Visual Studio 2010 (or serial communicator) and HyperTerminal. **The issue is sending a bit at a time!**

HyperTerminal:

```
Baud rate 9600
DTR on
Data bits=8, Stop bits=1, Parity=None
Set chars: Eof=0x00, Error=0x00, Break=0x00, Event=0x00, Xon=0x11, Xoff=0x13
Handflow: ControlHandShake=(DTR_CONTROL, CTS_HANDSHAKE, ERROR_ABORT), FlowReplace=    (TRANSMIT_TOGGLE, RTS_HANDSHAKE, XOFF_CONTINUE), XonLimit=80, XoffLimit=200
Set timeouts: ReadInterval=10, ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0,     ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=0, WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0, WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=5000
```

and Program/serial communication:

```
Baud rate 9600
DTR on
Data bits=8, Stop bits=1, Parity=None
Set chars: Eof=0x00, Error=0x00, Break=0x00, Event=0x00, Xon=0x11, Xoff=0x13
Handflow: ControlHandShake=(DTR_CONTROL, CTS_HANDSHAKE, ERROR_ABORT), FlowReplace=    (TRANSMIT_TOGGLE, RTS_HANDSHAKE, XOFF_CONTINUE), XonLimit=80, XoffLimit=200
```

An X sec wait in program code.

Comment: Hans thanks for the advise. I have configured my VS "program" to mirror hyperterminal (the com program working) exactly the code for this is in the update section of my post. IS IT THAT HyperTerminal is sending each byte and the others as a group? (how would i correct this?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I last did serial work -- but it was *very* clear in those days that your software on the computer *had* to be configured exactly as the hardware device required. Your non-working example doesn't have DTR or RTS raised, and that's exactly what the board appears to require.

Since software on a full-powered computer is usually far easier to modify than hardware on an embedded board, it'd make sense to look into the configuration options available in your serial software -- any tolerable piece of software will have those settings to fiddle with. If not, I liked both [Qmodem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmodem) and [ProComm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProComm), though I had friends that were adamant that [Telix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telix) was the nicer tool. (I had some Trade Wars scripts for Telix that were amazing...)

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I have configured the "program" to mirror hyperterminal (the com program working) exactly the code for this is in the update section of my post. IS IT THAT HyperTerminal is sending each byte and the others as a group? (how would i correct this?)

Comment: Well, it's a serial device; by definition, every character sent to it is sent one bit at a time for all eight bits regardless of any IO buffering that the operating system may perform on your behalf. Note that you still have `RTS` commented out in your updated code -- if you never raise `RTS`, then the device and computer may never think the other end is Ready To Send. Are you _sure_ the output from your diagnostics tool is identical between the working and non-working tools?

Comment: samrnold, the hand shacking is exactly the same!! "update3 above"(except delay which is implemented in code for VS10). The main issue is the sending of the characters. For some unknown reason my Arduino Mega board only recieves one char at a time (with hyperterminal does, sends one waits sends next wait.. 'x' .... '1'... '2'.. etc) The VS10 program and serial communicator etc all send strings "x123y543"

Comment: If your tool shows that you've got identical settings, then I'm all out of ideas. (Do note that the very last code sample you pasted still has RTS commented out...)

Comment: Thx, i am aware of it, if uncommented(enabled) it creates the (request to send- handshake) which hyperterminal does not have. I have tried using the RTS but it still does not work. I think there is something wrong with the arduino buffer(serial buffer which can hold up to 128 (bits or bytes doesnot make a diff which 128bits/8=16bytes >> then wat im sending)

Comment: Dang. Then I really am out of ideas. :(

Comment: Thx for the help and advise appreciate it. Enjoy

Comment: Do you have access to the Arduino code? It is very likely that the receiving code in the Arduino is not handling the characters properly.

Comment: For testing purposes try, writing one char, delay 100-500ms then write the next char.

Comment: @Jeff, thx for the advice. i do have the Arduino code, works fine sending from hyper terminal etc(1 char at a time). does not work with a "string" (more than 1 char at a time) i have come right with what i wanted to do but still curious why there is this issue. (have implemented a small delay as stated above)

Comment: @richie za, If you can share the Arduino code with us, I might be able help determine why the inter character delay is required.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion: If you learn some C# and use .net API's it can be so easy to access serial port...

Comment: Have noticed the same thing.. C# the answer at the moment. Thx